# monerod logging of hashes submitted

Tags: monerod, logs

Is there any way to include statistics of hashes submitted, blocks attempted, etc, in monerod logging when NOT using a pool? Right now, the only info seems to be the hash rate per second in the gui, and none whatsoever in the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The "status" command in monerod tells you your hash rate.

The number of hashes submitted is pretty close to your hash rate multiplied by the amount of time you've been mining (give or take a few). The number of blocks attempted is... that same number. Unless you're defining number of blocks attempted differently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer; I'm aware of the way to calculate it, I was looking for a more explicit way to output it, e.g. for keeping track and logging.

Comment: The actual accumulated number is not logged/printed anywhere AFAIK.